# Unable to connect to firefox browser using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I am new to selenium testing. I am trying to run this very basic use case , in which I am opening firefox browser through selenium webdriver but it is giving me org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException. I have tried all solutions given in other similar post but nothing seems to be working. 
Also if I reinstall firefox , it is working for first time and then it is not working.

Selenium version : 2.48 Firefox : 33.1 Windows :10

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.SkipException;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestNGPro {
 @Test
  public void f() {

     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");
     driver.quit();
  }

 @Test
 public void c_f1(){
    Assert.fail(); 

 }

 @Test
 public void a_f2(){
     Assert.assertTrue(true);
 }

 @Test(priority = 4)
 public void e_f4(){
     Assert.fail();
 }

 @Test
 public void g_f3(){
     throw new SkipException("skipping b_test");    
 }
}
```

Below is the error in console I am getting :

```
    org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host                127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
     org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:117)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at TestNGPro.TestNGPro.f(TestNGPro.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
    PASSED: a_f2
    FAILED: c_f1
    java.lang.AssertionError: null
    at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:93)
    at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:100)
    at TestNGPro.TestNGPro.c_f1(TestNGPro.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)

FAILED: f
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055; process output follows: 
tartup
1490296405449   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {4ED1F68A-5463-4931-9384-8FFF5ED91D92} to C:\Program Files (x86)\McAfee\SiteAdvisor\saffplg.xpi
1490296405449   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
1490296405449   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
1490296405450   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1490296405452   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping fxdriver@googlecode.com to C:\Users\o2r-team\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous7601333361719984095webdriver-profile\extensions\fxdriver@googlecode.com
1490296405452   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: C:\Users\o2r-team\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous7601333361719984095webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging
1490296405452   addons.xpi  DEBUG   checkForChanges
1490296405466   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Directory state JSON differs: cache [] state [{"name":"winreg-app-global","addons":{"{4ED1F68A-5463-4931-9384-8FFF5ED91D92}":{"descriptor":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\McAfee\\SiteAdvisor\\saffplg.xpi","mtime":1489672943735}}},{"name":"app-global","addons":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"descriptor":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","mtime":1490295869875,"rdfTime":1415924238000}}},{"name":"app-profile","addons":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"descriptor":"C:\\Users\\o2r-team\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\anonymous7601333361719984095webdriver-profile\\extensions\\fxdriver@googlecode.com","mtime":1490296403775,"rdfTime":1490296403740}}}]
1490296405476   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Opening XPI database C:\Users\o2r-team\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous7601333361719984095webdriver-profile\extensions.json
1490296405478   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com installed in app-profile
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
1490296405634   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-profile:fxdriver@googlecode.com visible
1490296405636   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1490296405636   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1490296405637   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} installed in app-global
1490296405641   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-global:{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} visible
1490296405641   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1490296405641   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1490296405642   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on {4ED1F68A-5463-4931-9384-8FFF5ED91D92} installed in winreg-app-global
1490296405647   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon winreg-app-global:{4ED1F68A-5463-4931-9384-8FFF5ED91D92} visible
1490296405647   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1490296405647   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1490296405664   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1490296405664   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1490296405666   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1490296405675   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1490296405675   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1490296405677   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for OpenH264Provider
1490296405677   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1490296406713   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1490296406763   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1490296407116   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1490296407116   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 16
System JS : ERROR (null):0 - uncaught exception: [object Object]
JavaScript error: chrome://fxdriver/content/server.js, line 61: NS_ERROR_XPC_CI_RETURNED_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80570015 (NS_ERROR_XPC_CI_RETURNED_FAILURE) [nsIJSCID.createInstance]
1490296408825   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>

Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-P785QGVF', ip: '192.168.1.18', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:134)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:117)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
    at TestNGPro.TestNGPro.f(TestNGPro.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
tartup
1490296405449   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {4ED1F68A-5463-4931-9384-8FFF5ED91D92} to C:\Program Files (x86)\McAfee\SiteAdvisor\saffplg.xpi
1490296405449   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
1490296405449   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
1490296405450   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1490296405452   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping fxdriver@googlecode.com to C:\Users\o2r-team\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous7601333361719984095webdriver-profile\extensions\fxdriver@googlecode.com
1490296405452   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: C:\Users\o2r-team\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous7601333361719984095webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging
1490296405452   addons.xpi  DEBUG   checkForChanges
1490296405466   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Directory state JSON differs: cache [] state [{"name":"winreg-app-global","addons":{"{4ED1F68A-5463-4931-9384-8FFF5ED91D92}":{"descriptor":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\McAfee\\SiteAdvisor\\saffplg.xpi","mtime":1489672943735}}},{"name":"app-global","addons":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"descriptor":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","mtime":1490295869875,"rdfTime":1415924238000}}},{"name":"app-profile","addons":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"descriptor":"C:\\Users\\o2r-team\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\anonymous7601333361719984095webdriver-profile\\extensions\\fxdriver@googlecode.com","mtime":1490296403775,"rdfTime":1490296403740}}}]
1490296405476   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Opening XPI database C:\Users\o2r-team\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous7601333361719984095webdriver-profile\extensions.json
1490296405478   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com installed in app-profile
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
1490296405634   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-profile:fxdriver@googlecode.com visible
1490296405636   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1490296405636   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1490296405637   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} installed in app-global
1490296405641   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-global:{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} visible
1490296405641   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1490296405641   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1490296405642   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on {4ED1F68A-5463-4931-9384-8FFF5ED91D92} installed in winreg-app-global
1490296405647   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon winreg-app-global:{4ED1F68A-5463-4931-9384-8FFF5ED91D92} visible
1490296405647   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1490296405647   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1490296405664   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1490296405664   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1490296405666   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1490296405675   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1490296405675   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1490296405677   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for OpenH264Provider
1490296405677   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1490296406713   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1490296406763   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1490296407116   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1490296407116   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 16
System JS : ERROR (null):0 - uncaught exception: [object Object]
JavaScript error: chrome://fxdriver/content/server.js, line 61: NS_ERROR_XPC_CI_RETURNED_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80570015 (NS_ERROR_XPC_CI_RETURNED_FAILURE) [nsIJSCID.createInstance]
1490296408825   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:122)
    ... 32 more

FAILED: e_f4
java.lang.AssertionError: null`
    at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:93)
    at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:100)
    at TestNGPro.TestNGPro.e_f4(TestNGPro.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)

SKIPPED: g_f3
org.testng.SkipException: skipping b_test
    at TestNGPro.TestNGPro.g_f3(TestNGPro.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 5, Failures: 3, Skips: 1
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 5, Failures: 3, Skips: 1
====
```

===========================================

Comment: Hi, Can you try with the latest versions of FF, Selenium and GeckoDriver?

Comment: because you are using the older selenium version, try installing older version of firefox like 40 or 41 and then also stop the Automatic updates of firefox.

Answer (score 0):

For selenium version 2.48 it supports up to Firefox version 41 try changing Firefox version.  From [here](http://www.askmetutorials.com/2016/06/install-firefox-47-on-ubuntu-1604-1404.html) install Firefox v41.